# Wrong value while using property mediator in WSO2 ESB

Tags: properties, wso2, mediator

I have made a proxy service where the value of "Request1" property showing properly as in incoming request

`<s1:PALMUpdateCatalogueRequest xmlns:s1="http://www.example.org/prodcatItemWSO2/">
   <s1:updateproductCatalogueList>
      <s1:catalogueinternalid>1</s1:catalogueinternalid>`
      ABC
      `<s1:itemList>
         <s1:Item>
            <s1:custitem_prod_cat_item>390</s1:custitem_prod_cat_item>
            <s1:item_price_level>7</s1:item_price_level>
            <s1:typeofitem>PQR</s1:typeofitem>
         </s1:Item>
      </s1:itemList>
   </s1:updateproductCatalogueList>
   <s1:transactionid />
</s1:PALMUpdateCatalogueRequest>`

But,after calling a sequence when I am using this below expression to fetch the value of Request1,it's not showing.
What will I do to solve this issue?

`<property name="REQUEST"  expression="get-property('Request1')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You should use correct scopes to read properties. If your property is in the synapse scope, you can read it like this.

```
<property name="REQUEST" expression="$ctx:Request1" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```